# What factors affect opposite pole bouncing

Tags: magnetic-fields, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

I have two magnets with holes on a stick, and when the like poles are adjacent the upper magnet floats. When the upper magnet is held against the lower and then released the top magnet flies off and oscillates before coming to a halt.

[image]

 (above image from http://www.instructables.com/id/Magnet-Trampoline/)

My question is: what affects these oscillations and how can I maximize them?

There is air damping on the magnet and the friction of the stick against the magnet's hole that contributes to the damping, are their other factors? There is some relationship between the magnetic field strength and the magnet mass but what is it? Also what affects the frequency of this damped oscillation, again that seems to be mass but is that all?